# Showing independence of sample means and regression coefficients

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics

I would like to show that

$$E(\bar{x} \hat{\beta})=E(\bar{x}) E(\hat{\beta})$$

and

$$E(\bar{y} \hat{\beta})=E(\bar{y}) E(\hat{\beta})$$

where in the population it holds that

$$y_i=\alpha + \beta x_i+\epsilon_i$$ where $\epsilon_i$ are independetly, normally distributed errors with $N(0,\sigma^2_{\epsilon})$ and $\hat{\beta}$ is the OLS esitmator, and $\bar{x}$ and $\bar{y}$ sample means respectively.

In words, I would like to show that sample means and OLS regression coefficient estimates are independent random variables. Can you provide guidance on how to approach the problem?

**Edit**
I ran a simulation and it stresses the independence assumption. But it's contrary to @kjetil_b_halvorsen reply.

```
n=10000
boot=10000

xbar=numeric(); ybar=numeric(); b=numeric()
for(i in 1:boot){
x=rnorm(n,10,1)
y=1+2*x+rnorm(n)
xbar[i]=mean(x)
ybar[i]=mean(y)
b[i]=lm(y~x)$coefficients[2]
}

> mean(xbar*b)
[1] 20.0009
> mean(xbar)*mean(b)
[1] 20.0009
> 
> mean(ybar*b)
[1] 42.0018
> mean(ybar)*mean(b)
[1] 42.0018
```

Comment: Do you really mean $iid(\mu_\epsilon,\sigma²_\epsilon$ without any specification of distribution form, not, for example, normal distribition? If so, this is impossible.

Comment: I made an error; it should say zero mean errors. I think then it's solvable.

Comment: OK, but zero mean is still not enough, it could for instance be true if normal distribution but not in other cases.

Comment: Really? I did not expect that. I change to normal distributed error terms. For starters.

Comment: When the $(x_i,\varepsilon_i)$ do not have a bivariate normal distribution, it's unlikely $\bar y$ and $\hat \beta$ will be independent. Take a look: `n <- 8;
sim <- replicate(1e4, {
  x <- rexp(n);
  z <- x - mean(x);
  y <- x + rnorm(n);
  beta.hat <- sum(y * z) / sum(z * z);
  y.bar <- mean(y);
  c(y.bar=y.bar, beta.hat=beta.hat, product=y.bar * beta.hat)
})
plot(sim["y.bar", ], sim["beta.hat", ], pch=16, cex=0.5, col="Gray")`

Comment: @whuber thanks, helpul exercise. The pattern indeed shows dependence. But the covariance is zero, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, the covariance will be zero, as your simulation suggests.  One way to see that is to compute the covariance conditional on $x$: that reduces the question to the well-known (and easily established) result that the estimates of slope and intercept are uncorrelated when $x$ has been centered (for then the intercept is $\bar y$).

Answer (score 1):

In the normal distribution case, independence is tha same as covariance zero. So it is enough to calculate the covariance. Doing that, you will find the covariance between $\hat{\beta}$ and $\bar{x}$ is given by
$$
  \text{some constant} \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n x_i
$$
so can be zero only if that last sum is zero. So, in that case, you have independence (in the normal case, without normal assumption you can only conclude the covariance is zero).

Comment: Please see edit on top.

Comment: In your simulation you include an intercept, which is not in your stated model!  So ir is not the same model. Which do you mean, which is your intended model?

Comment: The one with intercept.

Comment: So edit the original post to clarify. My answer is for the model you stated first, without intercept.

Comment: Edited - sorry for the confusion

Comment: Will then edit my answer!